# How to show message after deleting row in devexpress aspxdatagridview?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, devexpress

I have ASPxGridView from Devexpress and I want to show message after clicking the delete button, this message could be html div containing text or java script alert message.
Any idea how could this achieved ?
I'm trying this but it's not working:

> ```
>     protected void ASPxGridViewCategories_RowDeleting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             Response.write("<script>alert('my message');</script>");                
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>         }
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bunch of properties [ASPxGridView.JSProperties](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_JSPropertiestopic) + [ASPxClientGridView.EndCallback](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_EndCallbacktopic) you can do it - please see example: [ASPxGridView - Client-Side RowInserted Notification](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q252397.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[JScript] In aspx

```
  function OnEndCallback(s,e)
    {
         if (s.cpAlertMessage != null)
          {
               alert(s.cpAlertMessage);
          }
   }
```

[VB.Net]

```
    Protected Sub ASPxGridView1_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs) Handles ASPxGridView1.RowDeleting

     CType(sender, ASPxGridView).JSProperties("cpAlertMessage") = "Your Custom Alert!!"
e.Cancel = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access the style information for a div and set it visible.

Comment: I can't access any control because devexpress grid does the deleting action using ajax

Comment: Check out the client side methods:  e.g. ASPxClientGridView.DeleteRow Method. http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewScriptsASPxClientGridView_DeleteRowtopic

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to show custom messages in the aspxgridview:

In the properties box, go to Settings Text, look for title, here you can add a title for the grid.
In your code, when you want to show any message, after any event, this include: not deleting, inserting, deleting, updating, add this code:

ASPxGridView1.Settings.ShowTitlePanel = True
 ASPxGridView1.SettingsText.Title = "CHANGES ARE DONE"

You don't need to show any alert messages from javascript, or using the JSProperties method, since this is done before the callback finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to add a ClientSideEvent for handling the EndCallback event. Then you can have a JavaScript function which sets the property on the grid, though we usually just have an ASPxLabel with ClientVisible = False when the page is loaded, and set the ClientVisible to true in the JavaScript.

```
function grid_BeginCallback(s, e) {
    // Whenever a callback starts, hide the result label.
    lbl.SetclientVisible(false);
}

function grid_EndCallback(s, e) {
    lbl.SetText("CHANGES ARE DONE");
    lbl.SetclientVisible(true);
}
```

This support message describes how you would do this pretty well:

[ASPxGridView - How to execute javascript after callback is completed](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q357351.aspx)